# Creating image tag in jQuery not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="myDiv" name="myDiv" title="Example Div Element">


        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

jquery.js

```
$.ajax
({
 type: "GET",
 url: "url",
 dataType: 'image/png',
 async: false,

 beforeSend: function (xhr) {
 xhr.withCredentials = true;
 xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer xxx");
 },
 complete: function (data) {
 console.log("yello");
 $('#myDiv').html('<img id="target">');
 }
 });
```

Simple enough question,

Why is this line not working?      `$('#myDiv').html('<img id="target">');`
When I examine the source of the page nothing shows up, no image tag. I'm not quite understanding why as I am sure I am doing everything correctly.

Thanks!

Comment: Try `$('#myDiv').html('Works !');` and see if text appears or not.

Comment: Where is your <body> tag?

Comment: Are you sure your ajax call is completing and your success function is being hit?

Comment: Are you using an inspector? If not the source will not reflect dynamic changes.

Comment: I am using the chrome inspector. Function should be hit whether or not the get completes (which it does). Body tag is there, im just stupid and ill paste it in now. .html('Works!) does not show up.

Comment: Do you have that code inside a .ready?

Comment: .ready? not familiar with that, looking it up now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your function inside a [.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/):

```
 $(function()
 {
     $.ajax
     ({
         type: "GET",
         url: "url",
         dataType: 'image/png',
         async: false,

         beforeSend: function (xhr) {
             xhr.withCredentials = true;
             xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer xxx");
         },
         complete: function (data) {
             console.log("yello");
             $('#myDiv').html('<img id="target">');
         }
     });
 });
```

This makes sure to call the ajax method after the DOM is loaded.

Comment: Answered as i commented, it worked! Thanks! Will check as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

try `console.log($('#myDiv').html())` after your code and see the value in your console, you will find the image there but it wont show in source view

Comment: i demonestrated this locally
https://www.dropbox.com/s/n93oocn8e2e2wxk/Screenshot%202014-07-01%2000.49.58.png

Comment: <html>
    <head>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.0.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="myDiv" name="myDiv" title="Example Div Element">


        </div>
    </body>

    <script>
$.ajax
({
 type: "GET",
 url: "/images/cone.png",
 dataType: 'image/png',
 async: false,

 beforeSend: function (xhr) {
  xhr.withCredentials = true;
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer xxx");
 },
 complete: function (data) {
 console.log("yello");

  $('#myDiv').html('<img id="target">');
 console.log($('#myDiv').html());
 }
 });

    </script>
</html>

Answer (score 0):

If the javascript you posted is the complete jquery.js file then what is happening is the javascript is being run before the browser has rendered the div tag so the jquery selector doesn't find anything, hence your console.log call returning undefined.

Here is a quick [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2L5cn/) I through together to verify your javascript, note that I wrapped the image creation in a `$(function(){});` block. this is jquery shorthand for document.ready(function(){});